# Raphael.draggable no longer works with Raphael

Tags: javascript, draggable, upgrade, raphael

I have been using [raphael.draggable](https://github.com/mephraim/raphael.draggable) with a project that I am currently building. I have upgraded to [raphael 2.0](http://raphaeljs.com) and now the plugin seems to have stopped working and I can't work out why.

The error message that I get is:

> paper.draggable is undefined

I've also posted an [issue on github](https://github.com/mephraim/raphael.draggable/issues) but as of yet no response.

Does anyone have any ideas why it no longer works with Raphael? I origianally thought it was how the raphael paper is returned, but this seems to be the same way as the older version.

I'd appreciate any advice/guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Raphael.FreeTransform:

https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform

You can disable rotating and scaling if you just need dragging functionality. Demo here:

http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/

Comment: Thanks :) I've been following the thread on Google Groups for the past week or so...